# Include facet_wrap in R line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following code to plot a line graph:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(-Client) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,color=factor(Client),group=factor(Client)))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab('Client')+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(color='Client')
```

It plots a line for each of my clients, but since i have too many clients, plot all of them in one graph gets pretty messy, I've been tryin to use the facet_wrap() function to divide the clients in separate graphs but couldn't figure out how to do this, so here I am...

There is a sample of my data:

```
         Client   Model_1      Model_2      Model_3    Model_4      Model_5
            1       10.34        0.22        0.62        0.47         1.96
            2        0.97        0.60        0.04        0.78         0.19
            3        2.01        0.15        0.27        0.49         0.00
            4        0.57        0.94        0.11        0.66         0.00
            5        0.68        0.65        0.26        0.41         0.50
            6        0.55        3.59        0.06        0.01         5.50
            7       10.68        1.08        0.07        0.16         0.20
```

Comment: can I see your attempt at using `facet_wrap()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a group over number of customer using module like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-Client) %>%
  mutate(Group=ifelse(Client %% 2==0,'G1','G2')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,color=factor(Client),group=factor(Client)))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab('Client')+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(color='Client')+
  facet_wrap(.~Group,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If I want to create 3 groups, I can write a if - elseif - else inside the mutate() to do this??

Comment: @ArturBraga Yes you can but in that case you should use other option like `%in%` and vectors like `1:3`, `4:6` and so on!